# Pull certain information from sheets into a main sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Is there one formula to pull information from several sheets into a main one.
Example getting Daisy Trucking Inc's information from A-N from sheet 1-8 onto there main sheet. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZJ2I.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5h3n.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckZr0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pAfD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw6iL.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2I4Z.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZXGt.png)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:N; Sheet2!A:N; Sheet3!A:N; Sheet4!A:N; 
        Sheet5!A:N; Sheet6!A:N; Sheet7!A:N; Sheet8!A:N}; 
 "where Col2 = 'Daisy Trucking Inc'"; 0)
```